# Bash prompt execute command every time a new prompt is displayed

Tags: bash, prompt

I have the following prompt in bash which shows the current git branch:

```
PS1+="$(git_prompt)" #git_prompt is a function in my .bashrc
```

which works when I source the .bashrc, but not when I change the branch, so the PS1 var gets only evaluated when I source the .bashrc, but it should be evaluated every time a new prompt is displayed. How can this be accomplished with bash 4.3 ?

Answer (score 18):

I fixed it now by using this as prompt

```
PS1="$green\u $r@ $red\h $r: $yellow\W \!$r \$(git_prompt) \n$yellow\$ $r"
```

before I concatenated multiple strings to one PS1 string, there seemed to be the problem. 
The trick is to write a `\` before excuting the command with `$(git_prompt)`.

So `$(git_prompt)` will be evaluated when the `.bashrc` is evaluated and

`\$(git_prompt)` will be evaluated everytime a new prompt is displayed

Comment: For anyone who finds this in the future: Note the enclosing double-quotes `"` around the string. Using `\$(git_prompt)` without those doesn't work.

Answer (score 16):

Your problem is that `$(git_prompt)` is evaluated to some constant string **before** it is added to `$PS1`. You have to add the code instead:

```
PS1+='$(git_prompt)'
```

Comment: this gives the error `bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `git_prompt)'`

Comment: That is really strange. Make a "backup" (`oldPS1="$PS1"`) and then try: `PS1='$(git_prompt) '`

Answer (score 2):

try single quote in your ps1

```
PS1+='$(git_prompt)'
```

i also suggest my [psOne](https://gist.github.com/younes-hamada/b9eb46212d6f66b85bdd) function

```
psOne () 
{ 
    ps1tm=${1:-01};
    ps1tc=(30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38);
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[${ps1tm};${ps1tc[$((RANDOM%${#ps1tc[@]}))]}m\]\u\[\033[${ps1tm};${ps1tc[$((RANDOM%${#ps1tc[@]}))]}m\]@\[\033[${ps1tm};${ps1tc[$((RANDOM%${#ps1tc[@]}))]}m\]\h\[\033[${ps1tm};${ps1tc[$((RANDOM%${#ps1tc[@]}))]}m\] :\[\033[${ps1tm};${ps1tc[$((RANDOM%${#ps1tc[@]}))]}m\] \w\[\033[${ps1tm};${ps1tc[$((RANDOM%${#ps1tc[@]}))]}m\] \$ '
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting, can you explain what the ps1tm is for?

Comment: @danielr1996 it the text mode (bold unbold blink underline {0..5}, in this functions it's set to 01 if no argument exists

Answer (score 1):

Want to see madness? This is how I construct my bash prompt:

```
# inspiration: http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/2LpQMi 
user_host_path="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot) }"'\u@\h:\w'
xterm_title='\[\e]0;'"$user_host_path"'\a\]'
[[ $TERM == xterm* || $TERM == rxvt* ]] && line1="${xterm_title}"
git_branch='$(git_current_branch " (%s)")'
line1="${line1}${user_host_path}${git_branch} "
line2='\$ '
print_time='{ printf "%*s" $(($(tput cols) - 10)) " "|sed -e "s/./˙/g" -re "s/.{6}(..)$/ bash \1/"; date "+ %T"; } >&2'
color_bold='\[\e[0;1m\]'
color_reset='\[\e[0m\]'
PROMPT_COMMAND="_rc_=\$?;${print_time};((_rc_!=0)) && PS1='${line1}\n${color_bold}[\$_rc_]${color_reset} ${line2}' || PS1='${line1}\n${line2}'"
unset user_host_path xterm_title color_bold color_reset line1 line2 print_time git_branch
```

I'm not a big fan of colour.